# How to use setcookie for only current domain?

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have a domain e.g. example.com which has various subdomains.

I want cookies to only work via:

http://example.com or http://www.example.com and NOT work/be accessible via any other way (ie. subdomain) and be HTTP ONLY.

Would the below work sufficiently?

```
setcookie($name, $value, $expiry, '/', 'www.example.com', false, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a cookie in php is:

```
setcookie(name,value,expire,path,domain,secure,httponly)
```

So your example should work.  http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp is a great resource for all things PHP (or, for that matter, HTML, CSS, and SQL).  http://php.net/ is a good source too.